# OkHttp response status code in onFailure method

Tags: android, okhttp

when I user the OkHttp Library with a asynchronous way like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

        }
    });
```

In the **onFailure** method, how I get the response status code to distinguish different errors. For example, Network error or Server error ?

Comment: onFaliure method covers only exception like timeout etc.. If you want to catch response error like 400, you can reach status code from onResponse method response.code()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I remember, `onFailure` gets triggered when you get no response. So, if your receive an error, onResponse will be called. You can do something like this in `onResponse`:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    switch(response.code()){
    //your desired catched codes here.

   }
}
```

And [official doc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-callback/on-response/) for `onResponse` method:

> Note that transport-layer success (receiving a HTTP response code, headers and body) does not necessarily indicate application-layer success: response may still indicate an unhappy HTTP response code like 404 or 500.

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1769

According to the link, above, `onFailure()` is called if and only if there were problems with the client.

If the request was successfully delivered but there was a server problem you can check `response.isSuccessful()`. If it returns **false**, check `response.code()` and handle the error.

Answer (score -3):

You check that using `response.code()` 
You can also make use of `response.message()` to get more info.